# Symfony 6.1.7 project didn't work and still reload without any information

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-20.04

Symfony 6.1.7
PHP 8.1.13
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

the project work normally on local test but in upload on server didn't work without display any information without write in log files , and the project/public still in loading

i think it's permission problem but i try to give the folder project 'all the permission with chmod 777 '  but without any changement

Comment: If u are using apache in prod, u need to install apache-pack and point to the public dir.